Android gradle: attribute civ_background_color (aka app.manager.dating:civ_background_color) not found
``Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     com.manager.dating.app-main-7:/layout/profile_thumbnail_circle.xml:85: error: attribute civ_background_color (aka app.manager.dating:civ_background_color) not found.
     com.manager.dating.app-main-7:/layout/profile_thumbnail_square.xml:113: error: attribute civ_background_color (aka app.manager.dating:civ_background_color) not found.
     error: failed linking file resources.`

`* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.execute(ExecuteWorkBuildOperationFiringStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:34)
    at o
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)

BUILD FAILED in 4m 13s
27 actionable tasks: 27 executed`
I was building my android project and showing me the following error
Android resource linking failed com.commerce.data.app-main-7:/layout/profile_thumbnail_circle.xml:85: error: attribute civ_background_color (aka app.commerce.data:civ_background_color) not found. com.commerce.data.app-main-7:/layout/profile_thumbnail_square.xml:113: error: attribute civ_background_color (aka app.commerce.data:civ_background_color) not found. error: failed linking file resources.
`My profile_thumbnail_circle.xml is below

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
